# urls.py in django

Tags: python, django

Here is the problem, the urls.py file in a django project look like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^testapp/', include('testapp.urls')),  #Here is the problem.
)
```

And I got an app installed, it is called 'testapp', so I wrote the `include('testapp.urls')` in the patterns.

The problem is that, Why should I put the `testapp.urls` in the quotation marks?
Cuz I tried to put it like this: `url('r^testapp/', include(testapp.urls))`, it didn't work.
Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your must import app in urls.py

```
import testapp

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^testapp/', include(testapp.urls)),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

ad3w has answered your question.  If you want to learn a little more about it check this out:  http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter08/